# Make python program read 2 files line by line in sync and conduct program on each line

Tags: python-3.x

This question is two fold:
Background: I have 2 large files, each line of file 1 is "AATTGGCCAA" and each line of file 2 is "AATTTTCCAA". Each file has 20,000 lines and I have a python code I have to run on each pair of lines in turn.

Firstly, how would you go about getting the python code to run on the same numbered line of each file e.g. line 1 of both files? 
Secondly, how would you get the file to move down to line 2 on both files after running on line 1 etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File objects are iterators. You can pass them to any function that expects an iterable object and it will work. For your specific use case, you want to use the `zip` builtin function, which iterates over several objects in parallel and yields tuples with one object from each iterable.

```
with open(filename1) as file1, open(filename2) as file2:
    for line1, line2 in zip(file1, file2):
        do_something(line1, line2)
```

In Python 3, `zip` is an iterator, so this is efficient. If you needed to do the same thing in Python 2, you'd probably want to use `itertools.izip` instead, as the regular `zip` would cause all the data from both files to be read at into a list up front.

Comment: +1. I've posted [a generalization of your answer for arbitrary number of files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23505739/4279). Though it is unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

File objects are iterators.  You can open them and then call .next() on the object to get the next line.  An example

```
For line in file1:
    other_line = file2.next()
    do_something(line, other_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses two Python features:
1. Generator function
2. File object treated as iterator

```
def get_line(file_path):
# Generator function
    with open(file_path) as file_obj:
        for line in file_obj:
            # Give one line and return control to the calling scope
            yield line

# Generator function will not be executed here
# Instead we get two generator instances
lines_a = get_line(path_to_file_a)
lines_b = get_line(path_to_file_b)
while True:
    try:
        # Now grab one line from each generator
        line_pair = (next(lines_a), next(lines_b))
    except StopIteration:
        # This exception means that we hit EOF in one of the files so exit the loop
        break
        do_something(line_pair)
```

*Assuming that your code is wrapped in `do_something(line_pair)` function which accepts a tuple of length 2 which holds the pair of lines.*

Comment: Thanks for this! It all makes sense but I was wondering which file path should be placed in line 1 and 3 of the script? As both the files are called for in line 11 and 12 so I don't quite understand this part. Great to learn about generators and iterators.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear. You keep lines 1 and 3 intact - variable `file_path` should be left as it is. In lines 11 and 12 you pass paths to your files.

Comment: There's no need for the `get_line` generator here. The file object is already an iterator, so you can simply call `next` on it.

Comment: @Blckknght the main reason for this function is wrapping with statement

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo: Hmm, that almost seems like a downside to me. The files you've opened in the generator function will stay open until the generator reaches its end, or it gets garbage collected. If there's you were to break out of the loop for some reason other than the generators ending (or `do_something` raising an exception), you might end up with the open files sticking around for a long time. Using an unhidden `with` statement avoids that possibility.

Comment: Theoretically you are right but practically there is no break in the loop inside the generator and OP claims that both files have exactly the same number of lines. Exception in this code can occur if file vanishes or we run out of memory. Anyway Exception inside with statement will not interrupt closing file handle. I might be rookie on SO but I'm not a rookie in programming  so let's leave academic discussion for a private chat, ok?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that allows you to process lines in sync from multiple files:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

with ExitStack() as stack:
     files = [stack.enter_context(open(filename)) for filename in filenames]
     for lines in zip(*files):
         do_something(*lines)
```

e.g., for 2 files it calls `do_something(line_from_file1, line_from_file2)` for each pair of lines in the given files.